# Exclude worksheet when converting from Excel to CSV in python

Tags: python, excel, csv, worksheet

I have an excel spreadsheet which has multiple worksheets in it. My python code converts the  worksheets to separate CSV's. I am trying to exclude worksheets if there is any empty worksheets.

Here  is my **code:**

```
def csv_from_excel(excel_file):

    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(excel_file)
    all_worksheets = workbook.sheet_names()
    for worksheet_name in all_worksheets:
        worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(worksheet_name)
        with open('{}.csv'.format(worksheet_name), 'wb') as your_csv_file:
            wr = csv.writer(your_csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            for rownum in xrange(worksheet.nrows):
                wr.writerow([unicode(entry).encode("utf-8") for entry in worksheet.row_values(rownum)])
    print('CSV files has been generated from Excel')
```

I expect the empty worksheets should be skipped.

I tried  `if worksheet.nrows > 0:` before `for loop` , but it's including the empty worksheets as well.

Comment: try to put your solution after worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(worksheet_name) in the for loop before the with clause. It should work. You can also use if worksheet.ncols > 0:

Comment: seems to be much easier with pandas.read_excel() and pandas.to_csv() (e.g. no loops, sheet name as an attribute of the object, etc)

Comment: Thanks @levdev . It worked . You are awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a tiny Excel file with 3 sheets (sheet number 2 is empty) and tried the following:

```py
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("TestMap.xlsx")
all_worksheets = workbook.sheet_names()

for worksheet_name in all_worksheets:
    worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(worksheet_name)
    if worksheet.nrows > 0:
        print(worksheet_name)
```

The output is as i wanted:

```
>>> sheet1
sheet3
```

Are you sure your sheets are really empty?

Comment: please be careful with the terminology. I think you created a workbook with 3 sheets. But you're right. It should work